# Application cookie is not clearing after logout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-applications, oauth-2.0, session-cookies, burp

After logging out and clearing all the cookies, still data transaction is happening in BurpSuite. I am using OAuth for authorization. Even I am revoking all the tokens of oAuth during logout. Any clue why it is happening?

Comment: How do you clear the cookie? According to the HTTP specification, there is not really a way to clear cookies from HTTP headers. Rather, what you can do it set the cookie value as an empty string or set maxAge to 0 or set the expires to the old date.

Comment: Yes, I am setting expires to old date, after that doing session.abandon and session.clear().